# Writing information in a structure to a file

Tags: c++

Alright so i have these two structures, Im sending them down to a function to be saved to a txt file.

```
struct Cost
    {
        double hours;
        double cost;
        double costFood;
        double costSupplies;
    };

struct Creatures
{
    char name[50];
    char description[200];
    double length;
    double height;
    char location[100];
    bool dangerous;
    Cost management;
};
```

This is the part of the function im confused on, i don't know how to take each line of this structure and write it to the file. Can someone explain to me how to do this?

```
file.open(fileName, ios::out);
if (!file)
{
    cout << fileName << " could not be opened." << endl << endl;
}
else
{

    fileName << c.name
            << c.description
            << c.lenght
            << c.height
            << c.location
            << c.dangerious
            << c.management.hours
            << c.management.cost
            << c.management.costFood
            << c.management.costSupplies;

            file.close();

    cout << "Your creatures where successfully save to the " << fileName << " file." << endl << endl
        << "GOODBYE!" << endl << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: you would have to write operator << for your above two structure. so that you can use it as want to be in your program.

Comment: Edited to what i think you mean.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a solution like what you wrote in your question all you need to do is put and end line after each attribute you write out.

```
fileName << c.name << std::endl
<< c.description << std::endl
...
```

As long as the information you were trying to output is all that is going in the file this should work.

Then you can read them back in in the order you wrote them. Just be careful when reading back in strings which might have spaces in them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the *overloaded operator <<* for your defined classes *Cost* and *Creatures*.

```
class Cost {
public:
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const Cost& c);
// ...
private:
// data member of Cost class
};
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const Cost& c)
{
return o << c.hours<<"\t"<<c.cost<<"\t"<<c.costFood<<"\t"<<c.costSupplies<<std""endl;
}
```

Now you can use it as follows:

```
Cost c;
std::cout<<c<<"\n";
```

For detailed information about this concept, you can refer the ISOCPP FAQ link on this

http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#output-operator

Comment: I've never seen something like this before, is there a simpler way of doing it?

Comment: @Baalzamon: This is the way you need to do it.Please refer FAQ page and learn about isotream concept. You can start learning by using/running the program provided in the ISOCPP FAQ.

Comment: Honestly don't even think we will cover stuff like this until the next class Data structures. We are supposed to use Advance file Operators. such as what ive attempted to do above.

Comment: @Baalzamon There are a number of ways to do it. Your suggestion is one of them but it is not necessarily the way he needs to do it. In fact, for this example it is unnecessarily complex.